# Fetch all emails from gmail of a particular label

Tags: python, imaplib

I want to fetch all the emails from gmail of a particular label called `important`. I am using `imaplib` and `python 2`.

Below is my code,

```
import email, getpass, imaplib, os

detach_dir = '.' 
user = raw_input("Enter your GMail username:")
pwd = getpass.getpass("Enter your password: ")



# connecting to the gmail imap server
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login(user,pwd)

m.select("important") 

resp, items = m.search(None, "ALL")

items = items[0].split() 

print len(items)

for emailid in items:
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
    email_body = data[0][1] 
    mail = email.message_from_string(email_body) 


    if mail.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
        continue

    print "["+mail["From"]+"] :" + mail["Subject"]


    for part in mail.walk():

        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue


        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue



        filename = mail["From"] + "_hw1answer"

        att_path = os.path.join(detach_dir, filename)


        if not os.path.isfile(att_path) :

            fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
            fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            fp.close()
```

The error is showing,

```
imaplib.error: command SEARCH illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states SELECTED
```

But, if I use INBOX then it is working.

Working when `m.select("inbox")`

What is the recommended way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

`m.select("important")` failed.

If you want the special starred folder, it is probably named "[Gmail]/Important".  Use the list() command to find the names used by the server.